# how to convert sql statement to LINQ in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

how to covert to LINQ :

```
from p in Product
join c in Catalog on c.Id equals p.CatalogId
join m in Manufacturer on m.Id equals p.ManufacturerId
where p.Active == 1
select new { Name = p.Name, CatalogId = p.CatalogId,
ManufacturerId =           p.ManufacturerId, CatalogName = c.Name,   
ManufacturerName = m.Name };
```

help!

Comment: What does your domain model look like for Product, Catalog, and Manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to translate the query literally. In LINQ, you don't need to join entities as long as they already have a relationship because LINQ will automatically use the relationship to join the entities:

So assuming your `Product` has a `Catalog` property which in turn has `Manufacturer` property, you can write your LINQ without joins like this:

```
from p in Product
where p.Active == 1
select new { 
  Name = p.Name, 
  CatalogId = p.CatalogId,
  ManufacturerId = p.ManufacturerId, 
  CatalogName = p.Catalog.Name,   
  ManufacturerName = p.Manufacturer.Name };
```

Comment: a Product has a property ManufacturerId, This doesn't mean that Product has a property Manufacturer and I'm not sure if a manufactures object necessarily has a Name. I agree that it might be wise to create such properties, but you are not obliged to.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to build a temp result after the first join and use it as the first sequence in the second join

```
var result = product.Where(p => p.Active == 1),  // 1st sequence
    .join(catalog,          // 2nd sequence
        p => p.CatalogId,   // selector from 1st sequence
        c => c.Id,          // selector from 2nd sequence
        (p, c) =>           // take the elements where the selector match
            new {ManufacturerId = p.ManufacturerId,
                 Name = p.Name,
                 CatalogId =  p.CatalogId,
                 CatalogName = c.Name})   // result is 1st sequence next join
    .Join(Manufacturer,                   // 2nd sequence 2nd join
        r => r.ManufacturerId,            // selector result 1st join
        m => m.Id,                        // selector 2nd sequence 2nd join
        (r, m) =>                         // two elements where the selectors match
            new {Name = r.Name,           // build the result object
                 CatalogId = r.CatalogId,
                 ManufacturerId = r.ManufacturerId,
                 CatalogName = r.CatalogName,
                 ManumfacturerName = r.Name});
```

Answer (score -1):

Piece of cake ^^

Just call ToString() method of IQueryable will return SQL Representation.

```
var query = from p in Product
            join c in Catalog on c.Id equals p.CatalogId
            join m in Manufacturer on m.Id equals p.ManufacturerId
            where p.Active == 1;
string sqlQuery = query.ToString(); //SQL Query Saved Here
```

Comment: They want the other way around.

Comment: no , i mean like that db.tbl_products.Where().Select()... but in don't know